# How does irreducibility of a polynomial imply degree of extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If we are given a polynomial that is irreducible over $F$ of degree $n$ that is satisfied by $a$ (i.e. $f(a)=0$) for algebraic $a\in E$ in a field extension $E/F$, can we conclude that $[E:F]=n$? Why? I am a little confused with the definition of a degree of a field extension.

Comment: In such a case you can only infer $[E:F] \geq n$. To convince yourself you may take $E=\mathbb{R}, F=\mathbb{Q} $ and note that $\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb {R} $ is a root of irreducible polynomial $x^2-2\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Degree of a field extension $E$ over a subfield $F$ is the dimension of $E$ viewed as a vector space over $F$.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot, but you can say $[F(a):F]=n$. The extension $F(a)$ is a vector space over the field $F$, with basis $\{1, a, a^2,\ldots, a^{n-1}\}$: they are generators since all other powers of a can be written as a linear combination of these using the given polynomial $f$, and they are lineraly independent by the irreducibility of $f$, the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$. The degree of the extension is per definition the dimension of the extension as vector space.

From $[E:F]=n$ you may then deduce $E=F(a)$, but in general $F(a)$ is only contained in $E$.

Comment: Thank you. So for this to be true, $f$ does not even necessarily have to be a minimal polynomial?

Comment: If $f$ is irreducible, and $f(a)=0$, it is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$ (modulo dividing it by its leading term if this is not 1).

Comment: Isn't $f$ supposed to be unique as well? This is not assumed in my question.